# Does $(1-(1-p)^n)^\frac{n}{2} =o(1)$ when $p < \frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: probability

Does $(1-(1-p)^n)^\frac{n}{2} =o(1)$ when $p < \frac{1}{2}$? Given the context where this question arises, I believe it should. But I'm having trouble showing it. I've done the following:

\begin{align*}
    (1-(1-p)^n)^\frac{n}{2} &\leq (1-e^{-np})^{\frac{n}{2}}\\
    &\leq (e^{-e^{-np}})^\frac{n}{2}\\
    &= \big(\frac{1}{e^{e^{-np}}}\big)^\frac{n}{2}
\end{align*}

But I don't think these approximations will work because I believe what's inside the brackets goes to 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: It is because the limit is not $0$: $\log (1-(1-p)^n)^\frac{n}{2} \sim -\frac{n}{2} (1-p)^n$

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what you did. Why did you take the log?

Comment: Why not ? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: How does taking the log help show that the limit is zero?

Answer (score 1):

When $0<p<\frac{1}{2}$
$$(1-(1-p)^n)^\frac{n}{2} = {\Large e}^{\frac{n}{2} \ln(1-(1-p)^n)} \sim {\Large e}^{-\frac{n}{2} (1-p)^n} \to 1$$